# using a lookup table in R converts the class of all variables to factors

Tags: r, lookup

I want to use a lookup table to find and replace matching values in a data frame but when I apply the lookup table it changes all of the variables in the data frame to factor. Is there a way to apply this lookup table while not changing the class of the variables?

Here is my data:

```
df <- structure(list(year = c(2008, 2008, 2008, 2010, 2009, 2009, 2011, 
2007, 2011, 2009, 2007, 2008, 2010, 2006, 2009, 2010, 2009, 2006, 
2009, 2008), change_occurred = c("true", "false", "true", "false", 
"false", "true", "false", "false", "false", "false", "false", 
"false", "true", "false", "false", "true", "false", "false", 
"false", "false"), agent_01 = c("harvest", "none", "development", 
"none", "none", "agriculture", "none", "none", "none", "none", 
"none", "none", "insect_disease_defo", "none", "none", "insect_disease_defo", 
"none", "none", "none", "none"), agent_01_conc = c("harvest_60", 
"none", "development", "none", "none", "agriculture", "none", 
"none", "none", "none", "none", "none", "insect_disease_defo", 
"none", "none", "insect_disease_defo", "none", "none", "none", 
"none"), ha_affect = c(3.87, 0, 1.134, 0, 0, 1.44, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1.8, 0, 0, 2.43, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("year", "change_occurred", 
"agent_01", "agent_01_conc", "ha_affect"), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Structure of `df`:

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ year           : num  2008 2008 2008 2010 2009 ...
 $ change_occurred: chr  "true" "false" "true" "false" ...
 $ agent_01       : chr  "harvest" "none" "development" "none" ...
 $ agent_01_conc  : chr  "harvest_60" "none" "development" "none" ...
 $ ha_affect      : num  3.87 0 1.13 0 0 ...
```

And this is my lookup table:

```
lookup <- structure(c("harvest_0", "harvest_10", "harvest_20", "harvest_30", 
"harvest_40", "harvest_50", "harvest_60", "harvest_70", "harvest_80", 
"harvest_90", "harvest_00_20", "harvest_00_20", "harvest_00_20", 
"harvest_30_60", "harvest_30_60", "harvest_30_60", "harvest_30_60", 
"harvest_70_90", "harvest_70_90", "harvest_70_90"), .Dim = c(10L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("list", "val")))
```

Now I use the lookup table to find any match in `lookup$list`, if it finds a match, then replace it with the value in `lookup$val`.

```
g <- sapply(df, function(x) { 
  tmp = lookup[, 2][match(x, lookup[, 1])] 
  ifelse(is.na(tmp), x, tmp) 
})
```

Now I coerce it into a dataframe...

```
g.df <- as.data.frame(g)
```

But now the structure of the variables are all factor.

```
str(g.df)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ year           : Factor w/ 6 levels "2006","2007",..: 3 3 3 5 4 4 6 2 6 4 ...
 $ change_occurred: Factor w/ 2 levels "false","true": 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ agent_01       : Factor w/ 5 levels "agriculture",..: 3 5 2 5 5 1 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ agent_01_conc  : Factor w/ 5 levels "agriculture",..: 3 5 2 5 5 1 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ ha_affect      : Factor w/ 6 levels "0","1.134","1.44",..: 6 1 2 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Any ideas on how to prevent this from happening?
-cherrytree

Comment: set the parameter of as.data.frame as stringsAsFactors=FALSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use `lapply` instead of `sapply` as the latter converts to `matrix` and matrix can hold only a single class.  If there are any character columns, all the columns will be converted to `character`.  When we use `as.data.frame`, this gets convert to `factor` as the default option is `stringsAsFactors=TRUE`.

```
 g <- lapply(df, function(x) { 
    tmp = lookup[, 2][match(x, lookup[, 1])] 
    ifelse(is.na(tmp), x, tmp) 
  })
df2 <- data.frame(g) 
str(df2)
#'data.frame':   20 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ year           : num  2008 2008 2008 2010 2009 ...
# $ change_occurred: Factor w/ 2 levels "false","true": 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ agent_01       : Factor w/ 5 levels "agriculture",..: 3 5 2 5 5 1 5 5 5 5 ...
# $ agent_01_conc  : Factor w/ 5 levels "agriculture",..: 3 5 2 5 5 1 5 5 5 5 ...
# $ ha_affect      : num  3.87 0 1.13 0 0 ...
```

If we really want to use `sapply`, then there is an option `simplify=FALSE` so that it will not coerce to `matrix`.

Comment: So, no way to preserve the original classes?

Comment: @cherrytree just use `df[] <- g` where `g <- lapply(df,...`